# Deleting Element After Pushing

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

If I have an array where I am pushing certain elements to a second array- how can I delete those elements from the first array after pushing them to the second? Here is sample code:

```
for(var a = 0; a < arr.length; a+=1){
      if(arr[a].length == 4){
     other.push(arr[a]);

      }       
}
```

In other words, I know longer want elements arr[a] to be in arr if they have been pushed to other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a splice on that original array index to remove that element if you no longer require it.

```
for(var a = 0; a < arr.length;){
      if(arr[a].length == 4){
          other.push(arr[a]);
          arr.splice(a, 1);
      }       
      else {
          a += 1;
      }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because the splices change the shape of the array while it is being processed. For instance, consider the input `var arr = [ Array(2), Array(4), Array(4) ]`. This leaves the final element in `arr`, even thought it should be moved to `other`. `arr` ends up being `[Array[2], Array[4]]`, and only the first `Array(4)` is place in `other`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems fine:

```
for(var a = 0, length=arr.length; a < length; a++){
 if(arr[a].length == 4){
  other.push(arr[a]);
  arr.splice(a,1);
 }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function which takes an input array, and a function to determine if an element should be moved. It returns a two-element array, containing the modified input, and the new array into which elements have been extracted.

```
function extractIf(array, condition) {
    return [
        array.filter(not(condition)),
        array.filter(    condition)
    ];
}

// Specify which elements are to be extracted/moved.
function condition(elt) { return elt.length === 4; }

// Little helper function to invert a function.
function not(fn) { return function() { return !fn.apply(this, arguments); }; }
```

Invoke this as:

```
var results = extractIf(arr, condition);
arr = results[0];
other = results[1];
```

#### underscore solution

If you are willing to use underscore, you could group the input by the true/false value of the condition:

```
var groups = _.groupBy(arr, function(elt) { return elt.length === 4; })
```

Your original array with the elements removed will be in `groups.false`, and the `other` array in `groups.true`.